# KeyError: "None of [['', '']] are in the [columns]" pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, keyerror

I would like to slice two columns in my data frame.

**This is my code for doing this:**

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source.txt',header=0)
cidf = df.loc[:,['vocab','sumCI']]
```

**This is a sample of data:**

```
ID  vocab   sumCI   sumnextCI   new_diff
450      statu    3.0        0.0       3.0
391     provid    4.0        1.0       3.0
382  prescript    3.0        0.0       3.0
300   lymphoma    2.0        0.0       2.0
405      renew    2.0        0.0       2.0
```

**Firstly I got this error:**

```
KeyError: “None of [['', '']] are in the [columns]”'
```

**What I have tried:**

- I tried putting a `header` with `index 0` while reading the file,
- I tried to rename columns with this code:

  ```py
  df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace=True)
  ```
- I also tried this:

  ```py
  df.columns = df.iloc[1]
  df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
  ```
- Also tried comments in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239981/keyerror-when-slicing-dataframe)

None of the above resolved the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By the print you posted, it seems like you have whitespaces as delimiters. `pd.read_csv` will read  using `,` as default separator, so you have to explicitly state it:

```
pd.read_csv('source.txt',header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have white spaces **around** your column names, double check your csv file

Comment: This is also something to be aware of when using read_sql_query() : a column name in a table could have leading or trailing spaces. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

If you get this (or similar) error, check if your dataframe contains these columns. The following should be returning `True` in order for the indexing to work.

```py
cols = ['vocab', 'sumCI']
set(df.columns).issuperset(cols)
```

If the above returns `False`, then you'll need to process the columns.

A common culprit is leading/trailing space, so try

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Other common problems could be double underscore, double space or em dash (`—`) between words in legitimate column names. Then you may try regex to remove surplus space and underscores and replace em dash by en dash in column names, etc.

```py
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace({r'\s+': ' ', r'_+': '_', r'—': '-'}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

simply write code to create a new CSV file and use a new file

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 pd.read_csv('source.txt',header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
 headers = ['ID','vocab','sumCI','sumnextCI','new_diff']
 df.columns = headers 
 df.to_csv('newsource.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing this:

```
pd.read_csv('source.txt',header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
```

If you have any white spaces in the data you're will get an error, so `delim_whitespace` is included to remove those in case they're in the data.