# Using Pandas Style I get KeyError: "None of .... are in the [columns]

Tags: python, html, pandas, styles, keyerror

I build a dataframe using

```
    result = pd.concat([dmicao,dms,dmtime,dmdt,dmwd,dmws,dmwg,dmfc,dmvis,dmch,dmcl,dmwx,dmov], axis=1)#, sort=False)

    headers = ['icao','msg_type','time','dt','ddd','ff','gg','flt_cat','vis','cld_hgt','cld_type','present_wx','vis_obc']

    result.columns = headers

   icao msg_type              time    dt  ddd  ff    gg flt_cat   vis  cld_hgt cld_type present_wx vis_obc
0   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 00:53  1:00  260  10 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
1   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 01:53  1:00  240   9 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
2   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 02:53  1:00  260   6 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
3   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 03:53  1:00  250   5 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
4   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 04:53  1:00  240   4 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
5   KLAX  ROUTINE  2019-10-14 05:53  1:00  250   5 -9999     VFR  10.0     9999     9999       None   -9999
```

This is a combination of objects and int64. I have build a html file no problem using code *** pd.to_html ***

I have the html file. I would like to color coat the background the cld_hgt depending on the value

I used

```
def _color_red_or_green(val):
    if val>2500: 
        color = 'red' 
    else: 
        color = 'green'
    return('color: %s' % color)

highlighted=df.style.apply(_color_red_or_green,subset=df['cld_hgt'])

with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(highlighted.render())
    f.write(df)
```

It give an error.

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 2000, 2200,\n            2200, 2200, 9999, 2500, 2500, 2700, 2600, 3000, 9999, 9999, 9999,\n            9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,\n       9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999,\n            9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

I looked up a similar problem but I am unable to figure out the issue. I have a feeling it might be the syntax of the code I am using. Here's the similar problem. [KeyError: "None of [['', '']] are in the [columns]" pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976930/keyerror-none-of-are-in-the-columns-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass only the column name in your subset variable. Also, your function should return a list with the same length as your column.

```py
def _color_red_or_green(val): 
    conditions = val > 2500
    results = [] 
    for v in conditions:
        if v:
            color = "red"
        else:
            color = "green" 
        results.append(f"color : {color}") 
    return results 

highlighted=df.style.apply(_color_red_or_green,subset=['cld_hgt'])
```

Comment: I now get an a Value Error. ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index cld_hgt')